# Passing information from one user control to another 

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, user-controls

I have a webpage having two user control uc1 and uc2.
When user clicks a html server control on the page, i want to pass some property value of uc1 to uc2. How do i do that?

Thanks,
syd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the property or call a method
eg.

```
uc2.propertyX = uc1.propertyY;
```

or call a method

```
 uc2.propertyXChange(uc1.propertyY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place a function on the parent page which handles the transfer of data between the various user controls.  Call it like: `this.page.myfunctioncall(x, y)`